# what makes MSI to choose HKLM/SOFTWARE over HKLM/SOFTWARE/Wow6432Node

Tags: windows-installer

The MSI package itself is in x64 but the registry key defined in the package(HKLM/SOFTWARE/[Key]) was written to Wow6432Node in a 64bit system.

I'm using InstallShield as the tool.

The registry key defined is like: "HKLM\SOFTWARE\[software]"

and I have a Process Monitor entry when the package was deploying:

```
msiexec.exe RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\[software]    SUCCESS
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You should say which tool you are using to build your MSI, and what your definition of the registry entry looks like, but the most obvious explanation is that the containing component is a 32-bit component. It should be marked as a 64-bit component to write to the native 64-bit registry. A 64-bit MSI can write to both 32- and 64-bit registry locations and file systems.

Comment: I'm using InstallShield and the key defined is like "HKLM\SOFTWARE\[software]". I have two packages that contain either 32 or 64bit version of the component, but they all written to "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\[software]" not "HKLM\SOFTWARE\[software]"